# phonegap html5 canvas touch draw size limitations

Tags: android, html, cordova, canvas

I can draw on a canvas of 1280x800, but on a canvas of 1920 x 1200, the canvas does not respond to touch. If i scale it down to a specific size, using css webkittransform, it will work.

I am using a Nexus 7, so there is no performance issue.

is there a set limit of the max resolution (canvas size), that touch gestures can react to?

this also happens when I attempt to draw on top of a large image.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: In my past experience, I've had canvas of over 2100 x 2100. But i've always kept the rendered area within 100% of the view-port size. It works real smooth on iPad. I would also suggest you make touch controls fit within the viewport, probably as a layer on top of the canvas. Care to share some codes so we can help you find the bottleneck?

Comment: James, is the resolution of your iPad the same as your canvas size?

Comment: Yes, canvas size at 100% width and height. But the bounds inside the canvas is set much much bigger. Then through the renderer, you should be able to reposition the 'camera' to any area desired. This way you can create huge worlds and the device only need to render the objects that can be seen by the canvas/ camera. Performance guaranteed!